# Finding RSA decryption key

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> David uses RSA cryptosystem with $n = 9991$ (modulus) and $e = 53$ (encryption key). Find $d$ (decryption key).

**$1$)** Find factorization of $n$ $$n = 97 \times 103$$
**$2$)** Find $\Phi(n)$ $$\Phi(n) = (97-1) \times (103-1) = 9792$$
**$3$)** Find $d=e^{-1}\pmod {\Phi(n)}$ $$d = 53^{-1}\pmod {9792} = 9053$$

I have few questions:
a) Is my answer correct?
b) I factorize $n = 97\times103$ using computer, how to factorize a large number without using it? (Hand calculator is allowed)

Comment: Problem of factoring large integers is intractable.

Comment: For (b) you can factor numbers by finding an $A$ and $B$ such that $A^2-B^2 = n$.  So for your problem of $n=9991$ we get $100^2 - 3^2 = 10000 - 9 = 9991 = n$.  Then the factors are (A+B) and (A-B).

Comment: Wolfram says $9792$ for $\phi(9991)$. Check divisibility by four. Thus the inverse is incorrect. For 2), you could have spotted $9991=100^2-3^2$ which yielded a factorization. For general very large numbers though we can’t do it even with computers – hence the fact that $(e,n)$ can be public without decryption being practically feasible.

Comment: @Mindlack My mistake for $\Phi(9991)$

Comment: Take $\sqrt{9991} \approx 99.95$, so check if $100^2 - 9991$ is a square. If it is then you found a factor, if not then try $101^2 - 9991$ and see if it's a square.  etc.

Comment: @Houston Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can factor large integers (say around 100 - 150 digits) with advanced computer programs, YAFU, MSIEVE, GNFSIEVE are good places to start. See https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=23078 for more info.